# User-defined environment variable having same value as a system-defined environment variable in windows

Tags: environment-variables

I need to define an environment variable that has a value similar to a system-defined variable.

For Eg: "PROGRAMDATA" is the system-defined environment variable for Win 7 and above having value C:\ProgramData. I want to define another variable say "APPLICATION_FOLDER" having the same value C:\ProgramData. Is it allowed to have such a variable overriding the existing system-defined environment variable?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you have another variable named `APPLICATION_FOLDER`, it's not *overriding the existing system defined variable`* - it's a separate variable with a different name. You can have two separate variables that point to the same folder if you'd like, but there is absolutely no purpose in doing so - it's like having two signs in front of your house next to each other that both have your house number on them.

Comment: The point here is I cannot use the existing environment variable so I have created APPLICATION_FOLDER variable. My concern is if it can point to the same value as a system-defined variable. I am facing some issues when i use APPLICATION_FOLDER variable. So wanted to confirm if this is feasible.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine - as long as you understand that once you assign the value, it will not update if the system defined variable is changed. IOW, it's static after it's assigned unless you change it yourself. But why can't you use the existing environmental variable? You would have to read it in order to set APPLICATION_FOLDER, so you're already using it. I think you're dealing with an XY problem here - you're trying to kludge together something to fix issues caused by something else. I think that *something else* is what you should really be asking how to do properly instead.